# Postgresql count last 12 month

Tags: postgresql, group-by, pivot-table

I am calculating the last 12-months count after joining multiple tables, my expected output is working is OK but it is not what I want?. I want to add another column with the name "Current Month", so the basic idea is if I see a report for the month **May**, then it will **start from Last year's May till This year's April** and May as Current Month, total 13 columns counts. My intuition says window query will help me out on this, but I am now sure how I can do that.

```
select
c.name,
  SUM(case when RTRIM(TO_CHAR(mor.sent_at , 'Month')) = 'January'  THEN 1  END) as "January",
  SUM(case when RTRIM(TO_CHAR(mor.sent_at , 'Month')) = 'February' THEN 1  END) as "February",
  SUM(case when RTRIM(TO_CHAR(mor.sent_at , 'Month')) = 'March' THEN 1  END) as "March",
  SUM(case when RTRIM(TO_CHAR(mor.sent_at , 'Month')) = 'April' THEN 1  END) as "April",
  SUM(case when RTRIM(TO_CHAR(mor.sent_at , 'Month')) = 'May' THEN 1  END) as "May",
  SUM(case when RTRIM(TO_CHAR(mor.sent_at , 'Month')) = 'June' THEN 1  END) as "June",
  SUM(case when RTRIM(TO_CHAR(mor.sent_at , 'Month')) = 'July' THEN 1  END) as "July",
  SUM(case when RTRIM(TO_CHAR(mor.sent_at , 'Month')) = 'August' THEN 1  END) as "August",
  SUM(case when RTRIM(TO_CHAR(mor.sent_at , 'Month')) = 'September' THEN 1  END) as "September",
  SUM(case when RTRIM(TO_CHAR(mor.sent_at , 'Month')) = 'October' THEN 1  END) as "October",
  SUM(case when RTRIM(TO_CHAR(mor.sent_at , 'Month')) = 'November' THEN 1  END) as "November",
  SUM(case when RTRIM(TO_CHAR(mor.sent_at , 'Month')) = 'December' THEN 1  END) as "December"
from analytics_outbox mo 
inner join analytics_outbox_recipient mor on mor.analytics_outbox_id = mo.id
inner join customer c on c.id = mo.customer_id
group by c.name
```

**Current Output:**

```
name                              |january|february|march |april  |may    |june|july|august|september|october|november|december|
----------------------------------+-------+--------+------+-------+-------+----+----+------+---------+-------+--------+--------+
ABC                               |       |        |     1|      2|       |    |    |      |         |       |        |        |
DEF                               |     11|      24|    34|     32|     19|    |    |      |         |       |        |        |
GEH                               |      9|       3|     7|     18|     22|    |    |      |         |       |        |        |
IJK                               |       |        |      |      1|       |    |    |      |         |       |        |        |
```

Comment: Note that `RTRIM(TO_CHAR(mor.sent_at , 'Month'))` can be simplified to `TO_CHAR(mor.sent_at , 'FMMonth')` or better: don't use formats that depend on a specific locale. `extract(month from mor.sent_at) = 1` is much more robust

Comment: Any such question should start by disclosing table definition and Postgres version. Both matter. Are you aware that the current month also depends on your time zone?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic result column names are only possible with dynamic SQL.

This should do the job efficiently, save the dynamic column names:

```sql
SELECT c.name
     , to_char(t.mon, 'Month YYYY') AS report_month
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE mor.sent_at >= t.mon - interval '12 mon' AND mor.sent_at <  t.mon - interval '11 mon') AS mon1
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE mor.sent_at >= t.mon - interval '11 mon' AND mor.sent_at <  t.mon - interval '10 mon') AS mon2
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE mor.sent_at >= t.mon - interval '10 mon' AND mor.sent_at <  t.mon - interval '09 mon') AS mon3
     -- etc.
FROM   analytics_outbox           mo
JOIN   analytics_outbox_recipient mor ON mor.analytics_outbox_id = mo.id
JOIN   customer                   c   ON c.id = mo.customer_id
    , (SELECT date_trunc('month', now())) AS t(mon)    -- add once for ease of use
GROUP  BY 1;
```

This compares unaltered values from `sent_at` to a constant value (computed once), which is cheaper than running each value through multiple functions before comparison.

Possible corner case issues with time zone and `timestamp` vs. `timestamptz` unresolved due to missing input.